# creating images slide show on mysql database

Tags: mysql

i have a table images in my database which can store say like four images for one product. i want when a user search for a particular product an image slide show is generated for that product using the respective image id of that product.thanks.

```
$sql5="create table if not exists product(
prdid int(10) not null auto_increment primary key,
type enum('house','car') not null,
p_date timestamp not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
amount varchar(15) not null,
description varchar(255) not null,
status enum('1','0') not null default '0',
prdfk int(10) not null,
foreign key(prdfk) references users(usid) on delete cascade
)DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB";


$sql6="create table if not exists images(
imgid int(10) not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(50) not null,
mimetype varchar(55) not null,
fielddata mediumblob not null,
imgfk int(10) not null,
foreign key(imgfk) references product(prdid) on delete cascade
)DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB";
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific of what is not working for you?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius, He wants his products to be searched and place images of those products in a one image slider.

Comment: ..and of course, without showing his slider code --by thinking we would code for him.

Comment: @mwas: do you only need a sql to get the images?

Comment: @jens yeh...i wont mind even if its sql only.thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select fielddate, mimetype, name from image join prduct on imgfk = prdid where prdi=<your productid>
```